# Code splitting with create-react-app and react-loadable is not working

Tags: reactjs

I've followed various articles, particularly these...

- [Code Splitting in Create React App](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/code-splitting-in-create-react-app.html#next-steps)
- [react-loadable/README.md](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable/blob/master/README.md)

Here's a example of the code splitting -- `getRoutes()` is called in a component's render method:

```
// Edit: commented out original `Loadable` abstraction to use standard `Loadable`

import React from 'react'
// import L from 'react-loadable'
import Loadable from 'react-loadable'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

import { LoadingIndicator } from '../components'

// const Loadable = opts =>
//   L({
//     loading: LoadingIndicator,
//     delay: 300,
//     ...opts
//   })

const AuthenticateContainer = Loadable({
  loading: LoadingIndicator,
  loader: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "auth" */ '../containers/Authenticate')
})

...

export default function getRoutes (isAuthed, browserHistory) {

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/auth" component={AuthenticateContainer} />
        ...
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

..but my code is not splitting:

```
$ npm run build

> my-app@0.1.0 build /path/to/my-app
> bash -ac '. .env.production; react-scripts build'

Creating an optimized production build...

File sizes after gzip:

  854.84 KB (+4 B)  build/static/js/main.1aa92927.js
  17.53 KB          build/static/css/main.36b767d9.css

The bundle size is significantly larger than recommended.
Consider reducing it with code splitting: https: // goo.gl/9VhYWB
You can also analyze the project dependencies: https: // goo.gl/LeUzfb

The project was built assuming it is hosted at the server root.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
For example, add this to build it for GitHub Pages:

  "homepage" : "http: // myname.github.io/myapp",

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

  yarn global add serve
  serve -s build

Find out more about deployment here:

  http: // bit.ly/2vY88Kr
```

As you can see, the build result is not chunked, but a single JS file.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Current versions used:

```
react-scripts: 1.1.4
react-router-dom: 4.3.1
webpack: 3.8.1
npm: 6.1.0
```

Comment: Do you get a different result if you just use `L` instead of your cool `Loadable` abstraction? I think webpack can't pick up such dynamic usage of Loadable.

Comment: @Tholle I've updated to just use the standard `Loadable` and yes, I get the same result. Also, it's the same single JS file if I use an async component as described here: https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/code-splitting-in-create-react-app.html#use-the-async-component

Comment: why using `/* webpackChunkName: "auth" */ `?

Comment: You might have to eject from create-react-app and modify the webpack config to enable code splitting. Some advanced use cases are not easy to do by default with create-react-app. Also note that there are changes in how code splitting is configured between the latest versions of webpack.

Comment: That's to name the different chunked files so that the have a meaningful name. It doesn't affect things when chunking does work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, I worked this out eventually...

I had a file at `/src/containers/index.js` which contained the following line:

```
export { default as AuthenticateContainer } from './Authenticate/AuthenticateContainer'
```

This allowed me to import my `AuthenticateContainer` using the following shorthand:

```
import { AuthenticateContainer } from '../containers'
```

rather than the slightly longer

```
import AuthenticateContainer from '../containers/Authenticate/AuthenticateContainer'
```

However, leaving that line in `/src/containers/index.js` also prevents code splitting as the `AuthenticateContainer` logic has already been bundled into `main.js` before we even try async loading.

Remove the line and code splitting works as expected.